# Short story about humans on the surface of a star

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, space

I'm trying to find a short story read in the early 90's, although it was likely in an anthology of older work - probably no earlier than the 60's.  I read it in English in the U.S., it was likely written originally in English, and had an odd and memorable tone.

My main recollection is that it involved humans living and walking around the (somewhat solid?) surface of a star.  It's definitely not Starquake / Dragon's Egg - from what I remember it was not a neutron star, and these were normal - if futuristic - people.

This has been driving me crazy for weeks because I'm reasonably sure that this story exists, but I can't remember how this could've possibly worked.  I think the star may have had a "crust" of sorts that was at a moderate temperature, but there may have been some kind of construct or force field involved.  I also vaguely remember that heat management was a key concern of the characters, and they may have worn special shoes to get around on the surface.

My apologies for the extremely vague description but I'm hoping this rings a bell for someone.

Comment: "The Sidon In The Mirror" by Connie Willis? The atmosphere is explosive, and no naked lights are allowed.

Comment: 'Lakes of Light' by Stephen Baxter comes to mind (but no special shoes).

Comment: GOOD LORD, it's "Sidon in the Mirror".  I can't believe you were able to ID this from a garbled 25 year old memory.  Incredible.  And now I have the rest of the anthology to read.  Thanks!

Comment: @sueelleker please add an answer and I'll accept it if you care about such things, but thanks regardless!

Answer (score 1):

As confirmed by OP comment in response to a comment by user sueelleker, this is *[The Sidon in the Mirror](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?40943)* (1984) by Connie Willis. The story was previously asked about and answered [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/100462/what-short-story-had-a-protagonist-who-was-an-orphan-from-a-race-of-mimics).